# i am not able to increase the xib view size on button click in it,

Tags: objective-c, xib

on clicking of the button i was not able to see the view(xib ie VPProcessNewJobDataVC ) increased in size , i have been tried priorities,layoutIfNeeded and all . i have written the button action in the same VPProcessNewJobDataVC.m file

this method is in one class:

```
-(void)menuItemQARequest: (id) sender {

  vpaController=[[VPProcessNewJobDataVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"VPProcessNewJobDataVC" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
  vpaController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
  vpaController.delegate=self;
  vpaController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
  //[vpaController.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
   vpaController.preferredContentSize=CGSizeMake(600, 400);

  NSLog(@"View frame is  %@", NSStringFromCGRect(vpaController.view.frame));
  [self.jobsSplitVC presentViewController:vpaController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

this method is in xib class:

```
-(IBAction)okBtnAction:(id)sender {

    self.tableView.hidden=NO;
    CGRect theFrame = self.view.frame;
    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(2.0, 3.0, 800.0, 1000.0)];
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
}
```

Comment: Please explain more..whether you are clicking the button and you could not see the next screen as you wanted.

Comment: what the purpose behind this ?

Comment: Please tell us, which view you want to increase, and in which view controller the button click is.

Comment: on clicking of the button i was not able to see the view(xib ie VPProcessNewJobDataVC ) increased in size  , i have been tried priorities,layoutIfNeeded and all  .   i have written the button action in the same VPProcessNewJobDataVC.m file

Comment: you have added your whole question in comment but you should add- this method is in which view controller and which viewcontroller you want to resize, at least mention this

Comment: constraints for xib are given in singleton class and that singleton class is being used in a view controller and in the same viewcontroller i want to increase the xib(view)size on clicking the button which is there in the xib.

Answer (score 0):

For resizing and relayout view , layout cycle must call .
try calling `[self layoutIfNeeded]` after resize the frame .